# Erro ao usar o módulo Time - Python

Tags: python, time

Estou tentando usar o módulo time para formatar no terminal o horário que o usuário inseriu num input. A função `time()` é organizada em `horas, minutos, segundos`. Acontece que quando o usuário digita, por exemplo: 7, 12, 56 dá um erro na hora de printar no terminal (deveria aparecer 7:12:56).

Aqui está a minha lógica:

```
import time

def main():
    
    departure_time = int(input("What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)?"))
    
    departure = time(departure_time)

    print(departure)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Nesse exemplo que dei, **deveria aparecer no terminal: 7:12:56**

Este é o erro que está dando:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpvig\Desktop\Projeto Enes\home1.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jpvig\Desktop\Projeto Enes\home1.py", line 5, in main
    departure_time = int(input("What is your departure time (hours, minutes, seconds)?"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7, 12, 56'
```

Comment: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7, 12, 56'` o erro está afirmando que o valor "7, 12, 56" não é um valor inteiro válido, o que realmente não é. Por que tentou converter a entrada para int?

Comment: Porque, posteriormente, vou precisar usar o horário inserido pelo usuário e adicionar 15 minutos. Aí pensei que teria que transformar em int para que essa adição fosse possível

Comment: Mas mesmo que eu tire esse int(), aparece o erro `line 7, in main     
    departure = time(departure_time)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Sim, veja a mensagem de erro... ela diz o que está errado: "`time` é um módulo, não uma função"

Comment: Tentei resolver usando: `from datetime import time` mas agora aparece o erro: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Vamos por partes: `input` sempre retorna uma string. Se vc digitou `7, 12, 56`, isso é uma string contendo o caractere `7`, a vírgula, o espaço, o caractere `1`, etc. Se passar isso para `int` não funciona, porque isso não é um número inteiro válido. Então primeiro vc precisa separar esta string em 3 partes e converter cada parte em número (pesquise por `split`). E só depois você passa esses números para `time` (pois veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) que vc precisa passar os valores de hora, minuto e segundo separadamente)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter sua string em inteiros assim:

```py
time(*[int(arg) for arg in "7, 12, 56".split(", ")])
```

Passo a passo

```py
departure_time = "7, 12, 56"
departure_time = departure_time.split(", ")
#['7', '12', '56']
departure_time = [int(arg) for arg in departure_time]
#[7, 12, 56]
```

O Asterisco (*) é usado para empacotar (packing) os argumentos em uma lista.

O código completo poderia ser assim:

```py
from datetime import time

def main():
    separator = ":"
    departure_time = input(
        f"What is your departure time (hours{separator}minutes{separator}seconds)? "
    ).split(separator)
    
    departure = time(*[int(args) for args in departure_time])

    print(departure)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```